# How to doget() or dopost() without submitting form,from an anchor

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, get, request

i know that this is probably asked previewsly but i didnt find a solution yet.
So the case is that i want to make a (do or get) request to a servlet from an anchor in a jsp file and not from a form.Is that possible?

Comment: Different javascript libraries will give advanced utilities around this, but the most basic vanilla method is XMLHttpRequest. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML_in_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: AFAIK, specifying servlet name in href will by default call doget() when that anchor is accessed. isn't so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click an anchor link, you're sending a GET request, so `doGet()` gets invoked.

**You cannot do a post request by clicking such a link**. HTML anchors are not designed that way.

You can use [**Ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), if you don't want to submit a `FORM`

or atleast you can  trigger a form `submission` `onclick` of it.

```
$("link").click(function(){
     $("#form").submit();
  });
```

Comment: "When you click an anchor link, you're sending a GET request, so doGet() gets invoked." This sentence helped me a lot,i completely erased from memory that anchors work automaticaly with get request.Thanks a lot.